# Run MAF Classification

Tags: python, github, classification, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to execute the `MAF` model code in `Colab` to assess the model's accuracy. Unfortunately, I haven't been successful. I would appreciate your help.

```
https://github.com/bghojogh/Density-Based-Classifiers

!pip install tensorflow==2.11.1
!pip install tensorflow-probability==0.15.0
!pip install tensorflow-datasets==4.4.0
!pip install numpy
!pip install matplotlib
!pip install pandas
!pip install scikit-learn

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

!git clone https://github.com/bghojogh/Density-Based-Classifiers.git

%cd Density-Based-Classifiers/MAF_Model
!pip install -r requirements.txt
import pandas as pd
saheart_data = pd.read_csv('path/to/SAHeart.csv')

from MAF import MAF

maf_model = MAF(num_blocks=..., hidden_units=...)

maf_model.fit(saheart_data)
accuracy = maf_model.evaluate(test_data)
print(f'Accuracy: {accuracy}')
```

Comment: Could you share what error you're getting?

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'maf'

Comment: please remember to share output (expected and obtained), errors and more details (along with solutions you have tried)